# What does the ditloid "11 D S (P W D)" stand for?

Tags: acronym

A ditloid is a puzzle where each letter stands for something and the answer is the full sentence. For example, the solution to "**T A 365 D I A Y**" is "There are 365 days in a year".

At a job interview in New Zealand, I was asked to solve the ditloid "**11 D S (P W D)**". The interviewer said he doesn't know the answer because someone else told it to him and he just wanted to see my thought process. I've never been able to figure it out and it still weighs on my mind.

Does anyone know what "**11 D S (P W D)**" stands for?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling :) It might be useful context to know in which country you had this interview, as ditloids often have culturally-specific components. Could you share that with us, please? It might help you get an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the country, thanks.

Comment: Since the interviewer didn't know the answer, and was repeating it from another source, it might be context-specific for a different context. My best guess for Generic Business Context would probably be '11 Delivered Solutions (Per Work Day)' but it would be very difficult to know for sure.

Comment: Possibly! I thought of "Per Work Day" during the interview but I couldn't figure out what the rest could mean. Perhaps it was even context-specific for that company!

Answer (score 1):

Possible partial answer:

> 11 Downing Street is the official residence of the Chancellor of the Exchequer of the UK. This is less well-known than 10 Downing Street, where the Prime Minister lives, however it's not completely implausible that it could be known in New Zealand. If this is correct then I don't know what the P W D part stands for...

Comment: This was one of my initial thoughts too; however, it's more usual to see this specific answer in a ditloid like "11 D S is the R of the C of the E" and I cannot think for the life of me how 'P W D' can be relevant to this...